# Finding the Biggest Rectangle with OpenCV detectMultiScale

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a project on birds that requires me to detect weeds. I have written the program, code2, below and it works. I however, need the largest rectangle to be shown on the image. I try to to this with code1, however, when I use this piece of code in code2, it gives the error:

> "line 21 for (x, y, w, h) in biggest: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.int32 object".

I don't know how to fix it. Please assist me, thank you!

#### code1

```
areas = [w*h for x,y,w,h in birds]
a_biggest = np.argmax(areas)
biggest = birds[a_biggest]
```

#### code2

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

bird_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("birdcascadeHAAR.xml")
gray = cv2.imread("trialpic30.jpg", 0)
birds, rejectLevels, levelWeights = bird_cascade.detectMultiScale3(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.185,
    minNeighbors=20,
    outputRejectLevels = True
    )

print(rejectLevels)
print(levelWeights)

for (x,y,w,h) in birds:
    cv2.rectangle(gray, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv2.putText(gray, str(levelWeights), (x+w-115, y+h-115), font, 0.5, (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow("img", gray)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: np.argmax() returns the index of the maximum value in the array. I think you probably want np.amax(). See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html#numpy.amax

Comment: I read the docs and it looks like np.amax returns the largest value in an array, however, I need the largest total array values essentially giving me the largest rectangle. Thank you though!

Comment: use print to check what you have in `biggest`. If you have one element from list then you may need to unpack it `x, y, w, h = biggest` without `for`-loop. OR convert it to list with one element `[biggest]` and then uses with `for`-loop - `for x, y, w, h in [biggest]`

Comment: When I print biggest the program correctly outputs the array of the larger rectangle as [922 551 322 322]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
biggest = birds[a_biggest]

biggest = [922 551 322 322]
```

you get one element from list and you don't have list any more so you should unpack it directly

```
x, y, w, h = biggest

x, y, w, h = [922 551 322 322]
```

Eventually you would have to create list with this single element `[biggest]` to use with loop

```
for x, y, w, h in [biggest]:

for x, y, w, h in [ [922 551 322 322] ]:
```

---

When you use single element with `for`-loop

```
for x, y, w, h in biggest:
```

then you have something like

```
for x, y, w, h in [922 551 322 322]:
```

so it gets first element from list `[922 551 322 322]` (which is `922`) and it tries to assing

```
x, y, w, h = 922
```

and it makes problem

Comment: I used your code to fix the program, and it works well. Thank you!

Comment: I have one question however. I currently print the level weights and reject levels for all of the detections, is there any way to print the level weights and reject levels for only the rectangle shown?

Comment: `print( rejectLevels[a_biggest]`, `levelWeights[a_biggest] )`